# marginal effects after caret in R

Tags: r, r-caret, marginal-effects

I ran a simple logit model using the `caret` package, and I'm looking for a way to obtain the marginal effects (AME). The `margins` package does not seems to work here.

```
library(caret)
library(margins)
data("GermanCredit")
set seed (100)
kfold.cross <- trainControl(method="cv", number=5, verboseIter=FALSE, classProbs = TRUE, savePredictions = TRUE)
GermanCredit.logit <- train(Class~Age+ForeignWorker,data=GermanCredit,method="glm",family=binomial,trControl=kfold.cross, metric="Accuracy")
GermanCredit.logitmfx <- margins(GermanCredit.logit)
```

Gives the following error message:

> Error in UseMethod("vcov") : no applicable method for 'vcov' applied to an object of class "c('train', 'train.formula')"

Makes sense to me, but I can't figure out which package I need in this case.

PS the $finalModel gives the log odds (/ratios).

Comment: maybe you can use `Titanic.train.logit$finalModel`. Otherwise a caret model can not be used in the margins package.

Comment: Thanks for your reply phiver. The $finalModel works for linear models, not for logit. It gives the log odds (/ratios). I added this to my question.

Comment: I recommend you supply a minimal reproducible example using publicly available data. This does not guarantee that you will get a solution, but speaking only for myself, I will not even attempt to find a solution if the code doesn't run on my computer.

Comment: Vincent, I have rewritten the code using publicly available data. Thanks for the suggestion.